# Operation results in exceeding quota limits of Core. Maximum allowed: 4, Current in use: 4, Additional requested: 4. While in 14 day free trial

Tags: azure, databricks

I'm using the 14 day Premium free trial. I'm trying to create and run a cluster in databricks (I'm following the quick start guide). How ever I'm getting the following error "Operation results in exceeding quota limits of Core. Maximum allowed: 4, Current in use: 4, Additional requested: 4." I cant bump up the limit because I am in the free trial. I'm trying to run only 1 worker on the weakest worker type. I've already tried deleting all my subscriptions and made sure that there are no other clusters being used.

Edit: Im thinking it might be because the worker and the driver each use 4 cores. Is there a way to use databricks in the free trial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think these are your options:

1. log a support request to ask for more quota (apparently not a thing for free\trial subs)
2. use different VM types for master and slave (like Standard A2 for master and Standard D2 for slave) because they share different core limits
3. Use smaller nodes (which I think you've mentioned is not possible), but it might be possibly just not with the portal

Comment: Free Trial subscriptions are not eligible for limit or quota increases.

Answer (score 1):

**Azure free trial is eligible to VM with total 4 vCPUs.**

**Note:** ***Free Trial subscriptions are not eligible for limit or quota increases.***

If you have a Free Trial subscription, you can upgrade to a Pay-As-You-Go subscription.

[Upgrade Azure Free Trial to Pay-As-You-Go](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-upgrade-azure-subscription)

For more details, refer "[Azure subscription and service limits, quotas, and constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits)".